# QTP Regular Expression Wildcard Character (.*) does not works

Tags: regex, vbscript, qtp

I am new to descrptive programming in QTP doing Regular Expressions.
I have a certain link, say `www.google.com` on every page of the application.

In QTP I've written code

```
    Browser("title:=.*").Page("title:=A.*").Link("innertext:=Google Search").Click
```

This does not work.
While when I append some character of text in front of the same code block like this:

```
    Browser("title:=A.*").Page("title:=A.*").Link("innertext:=Google Search").Click
```

This works for pages starting with A, But the app to test has many pages.
I am using QTP11.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does not work in the first sample?

Comment: Are you sure no other browsers and/or pages are opened at the same time? QTP will only work if the object is unique. Otherwise you have to add an index: `Browser("title:=.*", "index:=0").Page("title:=A.*").Link("innertext:=Google Search").Click`

Comment: Dude you resolved my doubt...! Thanks a ton

But still I did not left any of my tabs opened in IE though I dont know whether Mozilla or chrome were opened and they were treated as other Browsers
Sill Love You for solving this Muuuaaahhhh....!
     `("index:=0") ' solved it` `@AutomatedChaos`